# Word suggestion triggering onInput() twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code:

html:

```
<input name="q" id="searchbox-input" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off">
```

javascript:

```
$(function(){

    $('#searchbox-input').on('input',function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        let input = $(this).val();
        
        searchbox(input);

    });

});

function searchbox( input ){

    console.log( input );

}
```

*onInput()* the value of *#searchbox-input* gets written to the console. this works as it should.

on my android phone the keyboard has word suggestions:

[image: andorid word suggestion]

if you type in **A** e.g. **Android** will be suggested.

the problem: if i click on one of these suggestions, the function is triggered twice. the same input (e.g. Android) is written twice to the console